# Compatibility and consistency between two definitions of cohomology in two books (about coboundary operators and 1-cocycles and computing cohomology)

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, class-field-theory

I was reading cohomology from Neukirch's book, and there he referenced to Hall's book. The two approaches are almost the same (are they not?), and they should give us the same results (cohomology groups). But I can not see their compatibility and consistency, and I can not recover them from each other. My problem is that: **I can not propose the compatibility between these two books.**

---

Hall's book:

**15.7. Cochains, Coboundcries, and Cohomology Groups.**

Given a double $\Omega$-modulo $A$ we define $C^n = C^n(A, \Omega)$ to be the additive group of all functions $f$ of $n$ variables which range independently over $\Omega$ and taking values in $A$, subject to the condition

$$ (15.7.1) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
f(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) = 0,$$
whenever at least one of the $\xi_i = 1$. The elements of $C_n$ are called
*$n$-dimensional cochains*. $C^0 = A$ by definition and a zero dimensional
cochain is simply any element of A.
The coboundary operator $\delta$ maps each $C_n$ into the next, $C_{n+1}$ in
accordance with the rule

$$(\delta f)(\xi_0, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)\\
=\xi_0f(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) \\ 
+\sum_{t=1}^{n} (-1)^t (\xi_0, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_{t-2}, \xi_{t-1}\xi_{t}, \xi_{t+1}, \dots, \xi_{n}) \\ 
+f(\xi_0\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n-1})\xi_n . {\mbox something \ that \ I \ can \ not \ read}, 
$$

And let $Z^n=Z^n(A, \Omega)= \ker (C^n\longrightarrow C^{n+1})$, and let $B^n=B^n(A, \Omega)= Im (C^{n-1}\longrightarrow C^{n})$. The quotient group $Z^n/B^n$ is called the $n$-dimensional cohomology group of the double $\Omega$-module $A$. We write it $$H^n(A, \Omega) = Z^n/B^n.$$

In the part *something that I can not read*, **in the above formula**, probably it is written $(-1)^{n+1}$, but I am not sure.

---

---

I have some confusions about coboundary operators and 1-cocycles and computing cohomology, and I can not find where the bugs are.

[image]
In Neukirch's Class field theory, page 13, does the last summand of $d_q(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_q)$ written truly? Or should it be equal to

$$d_q(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_q)= 
\sigma_1(\sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_{q}) 
+ 
\sum_{i=1}^{q-1} (-1)^i (\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{i-1}, \sigma_{i}\sigma_{i+1}, \sigma_{i+2}, \dots, \sigma_{q})
+ 
(-1)^q(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{q-1})\sigma_q ?$$

I've seen something closely similar to these relations in the Hall's book (The theory of groups), but I think at least one of them should have typo. I know that they are not exactly the same, but I think they are not compatible unless for instance we replace the definition of Neukirch as above.

Also I have ambiguity about cocycles and 1-cocycles. If the things in Neukirch's book are correct, then I expected the cocycle should be $f(\sigma\tau)=\sigma f(\tau)+f(\sigma)$, and I am confused with $\delta(f(\sigma, \tau))=\sigma f(\tau)-f(\sigma\tau)+f(\sigma)\tau$, and I can not see the compatibility.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for pointing out, I will not do that again.

Comment: The formula as written in Neukirch is correct, your addition in red is false. This should be clear from the $q=2$ case you've written down, because the boundary formula as written in Neukirch *does* give the right formula for cocycles. I'm confused about what you're actually asking beyond that, since it seems to be about comparing Neukirch's and Hall's book, but I do not know Hall's book and you don't tell us which parts seem inconsistent to you.

Comment: @Thorgott I added the texts from Hall's book. Yet I am not able to see the compatibility and consistency of these books.

Comment: Is my question a bad question? Should I ask it on Mathoverflow?